# Rails: join query on association with class_name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :b, class_name: "Something::B"
end

module Something
  class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Assuming above class structure with actual table names `a` and `something_b`, I want to create the following SQL query.

```
SELECT  "a".* FROM "a" 
INNER JOIN "something_b" ON
"something_b"."a_id" = "a"."id" 
WHERE "something_b"."some_column" = "some_value" LIMIT 1
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
A.joins(:b).find_by(b: { some_column: 'some_value' })
```

but the resulting query is as follows, which has `"b"` instead of `"something_b"` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  "a".* FROM "a" 
INNER JOIN "something_b" ON
"something_b"."a_id" = "a"."id" 
WHERE "b"."some_column" = "some_value" LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to do it without explicitly specifying the table name as follows?

```
A.joins(:b).find_by(something_b: { some_column: 'some_value' })
```

Comment: Is your database table named something_b?

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following solution.

1. In module you can define the following method

   ```
   def self.table_name_prefix
      'something_'
   end
   ```

or

2. In class you can set table name as

   ```
   self.table_name = 'something_b'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your model name and the table names do not match `rails` conventions, which in its simplest form `table_name = SomeClass.name.pluralize.downcase`, then you need to define the actual table name in your model.

```
module Something
  class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'something_b'
  end
end
```

Above change should pick up the right table name in to the generated query.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work: trying it in console gives following error. (db adapter is postgresql)
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"`
generated query is:
`SELECT  "a".* FROM "a" INNER JOIN "something_b" ON "something_b"."a_id" = "a"."id" WHERE "b"."some_column" = 'some_value' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Pls post the query you performed.